# How can I log and save every click action in the app with Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have an Ionic 3 application and I need to log everything that user does in the application such as the button that user clicks or the page that user enters etc. After that, I am going to send these logs to the database. I tried to do this with HostListeners but it makes things confusing. Because even I click onto an empty space, it still continues to log. Acutally, I don’t want to write function to every single function into app, beucase I have already over 300 functions. So, I am curious about if there is any best practice for this situation or not. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want to save user actions into database?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do actually. I am going to have an endpoint for this. I just need to save every action user does when application is working. When user kills the app, I am going to send all these logs to the database by that endpoint. I just need to know is there any best practice for getting every action.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to save user actions in your database then you need to look every actions manually. In that case use following things. You need to track every events that user went through including: Click, Mouse hover, Page change etc.

```
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/util/Events/
https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle
```

Or if you want to add third party analytics then you can use following:

```
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-analytics
```

Comment: What I understand from your answer is that I need to subscribe click events in my main app.ts and as I catch click events I need to save them. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you need to handle every events to(example: click, mouse hover, page changing) save all the events into database.

Answer (score 0):

Simple log file appender for Ionic 3.

[ionic Log File Appender](https://github.com/SmartMoveSystems/ionicLogFileAppender)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I explained my situation in more detail in the text I edited. I think this library is not the one I have been looking for.

Comment: The HostListener decorator can be used in Angular directives to listen to events triggered by the host element to which the directive is attached. For example, one could listen to the submit event of a form:
@Directive({
  selector: '[appInterceptSubmit]'
})
export class InterceptSubmitDirective {

  @HostListener('submit', ['$event'])
  onSubmit(event: Event) {
    console.log('Form submitted!');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

Comment: It makes sense but it will also cause some additional code writing in every .ts file, won't it? This is what I don't want to do actually. I'm looking for a way that I can manage all these things in just one .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

user fire-base analytics to save user logs here is link how to save link

```
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-analytics
```